# Want to add hyperlink on ToC, LoF, and LoT but got Error using Hyperref

Tags: errors, compilation-error, hyperlink

i want to make the chapter, section, subsection on the ToC, LoF, and LoT clickable. I've read some possible duplicates, but i'm not satisfied and they're not answering my question. They're not mentioning about how to do that and mine is error whenever i only add `\usepackage{hyperref}`. By the way, the error messages are:

> Undefined control sequence \tableofcontents
>
> Undefined control sequence \tableofcontents
>
> Undefined control sequence \tableofcontents
>
> old toc file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

And i want, when i click on the list of figures and tables it directed to figures and tables. So far, i can't found about that.

I don't know how it's possible, cz i use many custom on my ToC.

Anyway here is my MWE. It's not compilable since my document is separated into some parts and not possible to include them all here. Sorry for wasting your times, but hope you can help me. Thanks.

**Edit :**
The LogFile said \MakeUppercase UnsupportedInPdfStrings

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%
%\hypersetup{
%   linktoc=all
%}

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\setlength\bibhang{25pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cl}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemma}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definisi}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Contoh}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{Bukti}}

\renewcommand\tablename{Tabel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Gambar}


\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}

\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Halaman}\par\medskip}}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
    \vspace{\@tempskipa}%<<<<<< REMOVE THE * AFTER \vspace
    \global\@afterindenttrue
    \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
    \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
        \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
    \ttl@finmarks  % Outside the box!
    \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{cover1}
\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}

\include{cover2}
\begin{spacing}{0.1}
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{spacing}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\end{spacing}

\mainmatter 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{bab1}
\include{bab2}
\include{bab3}

\backmatter
\bibliography{dafpus}
\bibliographystyle{unejstyle}
\nocite{*}
\include{lampiran}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to make a smaller example, all the include and packages are not needed to demonstrate the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but if i delete some package and i don't really understand about them, isn't it out of my topic, i mean with less packages might be not getting error, but when i add some packages it would be error? Even if i tried to delete the include, it still errors and give me the same messages, undefined control sequence toc, lof, and lot. Please help me.

Comment: Learn to shorten your tex file to create a minimal example. If you don't know if a package or a command or an include is relevant for the error or not: put a copy of your document in some test folder and try it out what happens if you remove it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry. I've deleted some unecessary package. Turns out there's no error. That was i said before. It's out of my topic cz i use a lot of package. And somehow, i believe there's crash between some packages which i don't know. And even after i delete, of course it would work normally.

Comment: I forgot to mention about addcontentsline. I use that on my separated files. Does it affect the hyperref? The reason is i use `\chapter*{...}` instead of `\chapter{...}`, cz i need to get rid of "chapter x" above the title.

Comment: I tried to read Log File and it said \MakeUppercase... UnsupportedInPdfStrings. Seems like there's an error there.

Comment: Well you will have to learn to diagnose a problem. Guessing around without facts is not the right way to debug. Your has around 150 lines, uncomment the \usepackage{hyperref}, check if you get the error, then start to shorten it until it has only 40-50 lines but still shows the error. Start with the document body and at first remove one by one the \include lines. At each step check if the error is still there. You don't have to understand latex to do this. It is only systematic cleaning up and removing of irrelevant stuff. https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\texorpdfstring` works for me. I just need to edit on my `\patchcmd`

So it becomes:

```
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\listfigurename}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\listtablename}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\listtablename}}{}{}
```